# potential leak of an object allocated and stored into 'annot'

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, mapkit

I have many of this annotations(about 2400), but here is my problem.

I get the following errors

> potential leak of an object allocated on line 81 and stored into
>   'annot1'
>        potential leak of an object allocated on line 81 and stored into 'annot2'
>
> potential leak of an object allocated on line 81 and stored into
>   'annot3'

And so on. Here is my code:

```
MKPointAnnotation *annot1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot1.title = @"A"; 
annot1.subtitle=@"A1"; 
annot1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.978954, 120.752663); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot1]; 
MKPointAnnotation *annot2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot2.title = @"B"; 
annot2.subtitle=@"B2"; 
annot2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.988607, 120.748703); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot2]; 

MKPointAnnotation *annot4 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot4.title = @"C"; 
annot4.subtitle=@"C1"; 
annot4.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.008867, 120.743637); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot4]; 
MKPointAnnotation ***strong text**annot5 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot5.title = @"D"; 
annot5.subtitle=@"D1"; 
annot5.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.016190, 120.837601); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot5]; 
MKPointAnnotation *annot6 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot6.title = @"E"; 
annot6.subtitle=@"E1"; 
annot6.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.024183, 120.743401); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot6]; 
MKPointAnnotation *annot7 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot7.title = @"F"; 
annot7.subtitle=@"F1"; 
annot7.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.055653, 121.509689); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot7]; 
MKPointAnnotation *annot8 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot8.title = @"G"; 
annot8.subtitle=@"G2"; 
annot8.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.070082, 120.713684); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot8];
```

etc

{

Comment: Are you using ARC? If you're not using ARC you need to release your objects after you add them to your mapView.

Comment: After trying ARC the same thing still happens. Where do i release it? I have the annotations in the ViewDidLoad. Let me know if you need additional info. @Freddy

Comment: Have you read the [memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)? Also, that code is very repititive, you might want to consider keeping the data separate from the code that creates the annotations.

Comment: Thanks Georg I will read upon it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using ARC then you should release the object after you add it to your mapview.

For example:

```
MKPointAnnotation *annot1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot1.title = @"A"; 
annot1.subtitle=@"A1"; 
annot1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.978954, 120.752663); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot1];
```

Should be updated to:

```
MKPointAnnotation *annot1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot1.title = @"A"; 
annot1.subtitle=@"A1"; 
annot1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.978954, 120.752663); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot1];
[annot1 release]
```

The reason is that your object reference count never hit zero and the object is never released.

```
MKPointAnnotation *annot1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
```

When you allocate an object it has a reference count of 1. If you add an object to an array or dictionary the reference count is incremented. So after the following block of code you have a reference count of two.

```
MKPointAnnotation *annot1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot1.title = @"A"; 
annot1.subtitle=@"A1"; 
annot1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.978954, 120.752663); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot1]
```

Now, if you call release on annot1 after you add it to your mapview the object isn't really released yet. This is because the data structure in your mapview is holding reference to it.

```
[mapView addAnnotation:annot1]
```

Once you're done with your mapview and it is released then annot1 is finally destroyed.

Comment: Thanks george, totally overlooked that.

Comment: But When I Use ARC, the same thing still happen @Freddy

Comment: It shouldn't let you compile if you have ARC enabled. [object release] causes an error message when you have ARC enabled. Make sure you release each object you "alloc".

Comment: OK I think adding the release helps it. Thanks so much. I did release all the alloc expect this annotations things. But is there any suggestion other then hardcode all 2434 annotaions like this? MKPointAnnotation *annot1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; 
annot1.title = @"A"; 
annot1.subtitle=@"A1"; 
annot1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.978954, 120.752663); 
[mapView addAnnotation:annot1];
[annot1 release]  @Freddy

Comment: If you have a bunch of coordinates that you need hard coded I would look into hard coding a .plist. Then when you build your mapview just read the plist file and loop through each coordinate.

Comment: I actually did a plist, but when the plist is done. It's slower than hardcode it. I wonder why.

Comment: let me edit so you can see what i use for plist. Can you take a look if there is anything wrong? @Freddy